# ¿Como puedo calcular factoriales grandes en c++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Me enfrenté al problema de calcular Seno a través de la sumatoria de maclaurin y se necesitaba calcular el factorial de un monomio

Después de quedarme satisfecho con el resultado empece a quedarme corto para calcular el factorial de 21 y las variables de long long no podían dar el resultado completo

[image]

Existe en c++ una solución para esto?

Vi que con una librería que aun no consigo obtener se puede crear una variable int de 128 pero no se si es lo que ando buscando o es una variable de 4 bits sin signo o de 8 con signo

Comment: Si necesita 19 miembros de la serie MacLaurin, probablemente tenga un gran problema con su convergencia.

Comment: No de hecho funciona bien pero quiero ver que tan lejos puedo llegar

Comment: No se puede ir muy lejos por la acumulación de errores. Pero si quieres, puedes probarlo. No es necesario calcular factoriales por separado. Por ejemplo, cuando calculas el `sin`, necesitas `x^19/19!`, pero es igual a `(x^2/(18*19)) * (x^17/17!)`  y ya tienes eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] quedarme corto para calcular el factorial de 19 y las variables de long long [...] no podían dar el resultado completo.

El valor 19! es ciento veintiún mil seiscientos cuarenta y cinco billones cien mil cuatrocientos ocho millones ochocientos treinta y dos mil<sup>A</sup> mientras que el valor máximo almacenable por una variable de 64 bits es 2<sup>64</sup> o dieciocho trillones cuatrocientos cuarenta y seis mil setecientos cuarenta y cuatro billones setenta y tres mil setecientos nueve millones quinientos cincuenta y un mil seiscientos dieciséis<sup>B</sup>.

Con una variable `unsigned long long` puedes almacenar 19!.

A día de hoy no hay ningún tipo estándar de 128 bits, por lo que te tendrás que conformar con una librería de [aritmética de precisión arbitraria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precisi%C3%B3n_arbitraria) como [Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/high_precision/use_multiprecision.html).

---

A) 121.645.100.408.832.000

B) 18.446.744.073.709.551.616

Comment: No necesitas nada de esto. Simplemente calcule factoriales con coma flotante. No necesitan ser exactos en esta aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Si alguien me puede explicar como es que mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long double factorial(int N){
long double resultado=1;
for(N;N>=1;N--){
    resultado*=N;
}
return resultado;
}
main(){
    cout.precision(1000);
    for(int i = 0;i<=2000;i++){
        cout<<factorial(i)<<endl<<endl;
    }
}
```

Es capaz de hacer semejante monstruosidad

Mi problema era como calcular 21! y terminé introduciendo a mi función números a los cuales eran impensable sacarle el factorial

[image]

Comment: NO debes calcular `21!`. Debes calcular `x^21/21!`. El primero se desbordará. El segundo, no. Por cierto, 
`cout.precision(1000)` no tiene sentido en absoluto. `long double` tiene 80 o 128 bits, no más de 36 dígitos decimales.

Comment: Te doy la razón en todo lo que escribiste pero explícame como no me da "errores" al superar el limite de 2^128 por que calculé factoriales que superaban en dígitos a 2^128 y eran correctos

Comment: 11754! es 19792618901050100553..., tu valor es 19792618901050100556... Debería ser suficiente para esta aplicación, pero solo hay 20 dígitos correctos, no 1000. Por cierto, sugeriría actualizar su compilador, `main()` no es valido, debe ser `int main()`.

Comment: 1754? por que mi código no supera los 2000

Comment: En que fuente te basas para decir eso? no es que no confié pero para corroborar

Comment: Lo calculé. Tu código no puede superar 1754 porque long double no tiene capacidad infinita. Déjame reiterar, lo que está haciendo puede ser muy interesante, pero es inútil para calcular la serie MacLaurin.